# Can we use setvalue and forkey attributes for a class object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have a class named "Book" and the source code is as following:-

**Book.h**

```
#import <"UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface Book : NSObject {

    NSInteger bookID;
    NSString *title;    //Same name as the Entity Name.
    NSString *author;   //Same name as the Entity Name.
    NSString *summary;  //Same name as the Entity Name.

}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger bookID;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *author;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *summary;

@end
```

**Book.m**

```
#import "Book.h"

@implementation Book

@synthesize title, author, summary, bookID;

-(void) dealloc {

    [summary release];
    [author release];
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

**Then within another class can I write:-**

```
Book *aBook = [[Book alloc]init];
[aBook setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
```

If yes then why?? Because generally setvalue and forkey is used to store data in NSMutableDictionary..

Answer (score 0):

Basically Key-Value coding is intended to work with an object's properties. [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001838-SW1) starts with the lines,

> Key-value coding is a mechanism for **accessing an object’s properties indirectly**, using strings to identify properties, rather than through invocation of an accessor method or accessing them directly through instance variables. In essence, key-value coding defines the patterns and method signatures that your application’s accessor methods implement.

The **setObject:forKey:** and **removeObjectForKey:** methods are intended to be used with dictionaries. You can also use **setValue:forKey:** method to set values to a dictionary. But, you can not use *setObject:forKey:* method for class objects.

One more difference is that *setObject:forKey:* doesn't accept **nil** as the value. Instead you should use *NSNull* as the value. But *setValue:forKey:* accepts *nil* and removes the key from the dictionary, which saves the memory.

*[Please someone correct me if I am wrong somewhere!]*

Comment: So you mean we can use setObject:forKey: to store value in a class object also ... Rigth???

Comment: But the coding that i have written above I got this from net itself.. and it works perfectly.. Book is also a class . . and aBook is its object then how it works??

Comment: Its working because you are using *setValue:forKey:* method. It won't work if you use *setObject:forKey:* method ;-)